# Using pushed DNS from OpenVPN with NetworkManager on Trusty Tahr

Tags: dns, openvpn

My company provides me a VPN connection that also hosts a DNS server for names that are internal to the VPN. Currently, it sets all my traffic to route through the VPN, which works but is undesirable. I'd like only DNS queries and VPN traffic to go over the VPN and everything else to go over the Internet. However, I'm not sure how to configure this in Network Manager. When I set Network Manager to only get IP addresses, it no longer automatically adds the DNS servers pushed by the OpenVPN server. How do I get it to work the way I mentioned?